# Deploying a project using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

I have created a project in Eclipse and built it using Maven. I need to deploy my project to my Tomcat server after packaging the project. How can I do this? I have already added my Tomcat server to Eclipse.

Comment: Do you use Tomcat for development? Have you considered using jetty for development? With maven all you have to do is: "mvn jetty:run" in your project root path, and you can configure it to auto-restart every time a change is made in classes, and it is really really fast, compared to tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While developing,  if you use M2E plugin, then you can still let M2E build the project and simply use *Run on Server* by right clicking on the project. That's the easiest.

If *Run on Server* is not shown on the menu, you could simply right click the project --> *Enable faceted form* and then check on *Dynamic Web Module* as in [this screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356421/maven-tomcat-projects-in-eclipse-indigo-3-7/6664354#6664354)

For maven plugin options, apart from what *@Ramon* pointed out, there's [t7mp](http://code.google.com/p/t7mp/) T7MP is useful from an integration testing point of view. You may refer to the configuration wiki page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is now an official maven plugin for tomcat [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html). I have used [the old version](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/) which seems to be the more stable option.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a web project to an Eclipse Tomcat server: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html

To learn about deploying apps to a standalone Tomcat server: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

edit (or create if it doesn't exist) your $HOME/.m2/settings.xml to include the following server block, this assumes
your `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml` has an entry like

```
<user username="tomcatuser" password="tomcatpw" roles="tomcat, manager-gui"/>

<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>tomcat</id>
      <username>tomcatuser</username>
      <password>tomcatpw</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Then you can deploy to tomcat with maven using

```
mvn tomcat:deploy
```

For further tomcat deployment settings for maven see

http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/configuration.html